# Proper configuration parameter names to limit array size

Tags: java, algorithm

I wrote a function that pushes an entry and then shrinks the size of array if it is large, like this:

```
public add(log) {
    this.logs.push(log);

    if (this.logs.length > this.configA) {
        this.logs = this.logs.slice(-this.configB);
    }
}
```

But I can't think of any good ideas to name configA and configB. Is there an idea? I think the logic itself is commonly used. Or should I use some npm module that provides a similar container?

Comment: If you found an npm module that did this, what names does it use?

Comment: My first guess would be `maxWindow` and `minWindow`. Or  `…LogSize` since that's the specific application

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I will use maxWindow/minWindow.